# Always got error AbstractMethodError in Spring SOAP Tutorial

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, soap

I've tried the SOAP Tutorial in Spring in this [URL](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/). I've make sure to follow the entire tutorial perfectly, but still got this error when testing the SOAP. Here's the error returned:

```
{"timestamp":1454299828677,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.AbstractMethodError","message":"org.springframework.ws.
server.endpoint.mapping.AbstractMethodEndpointMapping.getLookupKeyForMessage(Lorg/springframework/ws/context/MessageContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;","path
":"/ws"}
```

I've make sure the JDK is in version 8 and the web service  is running successfully. But still, it always return like that. Anyone has a solution for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this tutorial and is working perfectly for me.

I have created the application using maven and run it using the following command.

```
    mvn spring-boot:run
```

Now my SOAP web service is running and then I run the SOAP request xml in postman as follows.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:gs="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <gs:getCountryRequest>
         <gs:name>Poland</gs:name>
      </gs:getCountryRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

One more thing , set the body type as “text/xml” in postman request.

The following is the result i am getting

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:getCountryResponse xmlns:ns2="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service">
            <ns2:country>
                <ns2:name>Poland</ns2:name>
                <ns2:population>38186860</ns2:population>
                <ns2:capital>Warsaw</ns2:capital>
                <ns2:currency>PLN</ns2:currency>
            </ns2:country>
        </ns2:getCountryResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: hmmm I see. I'm using gradle instead of maven. The error message is shown in the client side when invoking the cURL command in the tutorial. Instead of getting response like you do, I got the error that I mentioned above at the client side